# Unable to retrieve Firebase downloadURL from .getDownloadURL() promise

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to retrieve the downloadURL from an image I uploaded to Firebase. No problem getting the correct URL inside the promise.

I don't understand why downloadURL is still undefined after I set it equal to the url returned in the .then statement.

```
let downloadURL;

    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child('project_images/' + imageName)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        downloadURL = url;
        console.log(downloadURL); //logs the correct downloadURL needed
      })
      .catch(error => {});

    console.log(downloadURL); //still undefined
```

I feel like I am missing something stupid but for the life of me I can't see what it is. Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it log the `undefined` before the one inside the promise?

It's likely just not completing the promise before you try and log outside the function calls.

Comment: I added a setTimeout on the console.log outside the promise to check and you were right. The promise wasn't completed yet! Thank you!